# Multiple regression : different subsets

Tags: statistics, regression

You run your regression on different subsets of your data, and find that in each subset, the beta value for a certain variable varies wildly. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Welcome. This question is off-topic for this site, as it does not have to do with programming. If you edit the question substantially to add more information, an example, research effort, etc. it might be a better fit at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). Read the [Tour page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) first to see how to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Usually coefficients (beta) represent the level of importance of each variable. If you see a coefficient is changing from one model (subset) to another model (another subset), it means the importance of that specific variable In each dataset is different.